# Moving from XAMPP to Webhost

Tags: php, oop, xampp, host

I've uploaded my custom webapp on host and I am stuck with this error for past 2 hours. Can you help me debugg it?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function isLogged() on null in /home/****/public_html/admin/includes/top_nav.php:1 Stack trace: #0 /home/****/public_html/admin/users.php(2): include() #1 /home/****/public_html/admin/includes/init.php(11): require_once('/home/****/...') #2 /home/****/public_html/admin/includes/header.php(3): require_once('/home/****/...') #3 /home/****/public_html/admin/login.php(2): require_once('/home/****/...') #4 {main} thrown in /home/****/public_html/admin/includes/top_nav.php on line 1

I will leave code of function `isLogged()`

> ```
> private $signed_in = false;
> public $user_id;
> ```

```
//Return boolean $signed_in
public function isLogged(){

    return $this->signed_in;
}
```

And first line of top_nav

> if(!$session->isLogged()) redirect('login');

The php tags are there, don't worry :))

RWX of all files are 777

Some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

> call 1st login.php then try if login success and not redirecting you should be set default start up url to login.php

I thing you do this

**Good Luck**

Comment: you have online link if yes then share with me